# Access JSON data in UI5

Tags: json, sapui5

I'm trying to access the JSON data from the below URL:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London

And get the below as response:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 174.77,
    "lat": -36.87
  },
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 8276,
    "message": 0.0568,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1407093366,
    "sunset": 1407130678
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 500,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "light rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "cmc stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 287.15,
    "pressure": 1017,
    "humidity": 76,
    "temp_min": 287.15,
    "temp_max": 287.15
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3.6,
    "deg": 210
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 76
  },
  "rain": {
    "3h": 1
  },
  "dt": 1407115800,
  "id": 2193733,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Kindly can you please suggest how do I access it in UI5?

I've done the following in order to set the model:

```
var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
jsonModel.loadData('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Auckland');
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(jsonModel);
```

I can see the response coming well in Chrome. How do I bind it to ui5 control? I've seen the binding syntax but gets either null or undefined error.

Please suggest.

Awaiting response.

Cheers,
AW

Comment: Able to access now. Cheers.

Comment: Please either delete this question or post and accept the solution to let others know that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just `sap.ui.getCore().getModel(<your Modelname>).getData()`

It's better to avoid the global model. You could use the view instead. Like: `this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(), "yourModel")`. The model is bind to the view, so the controls within the view can access the model data.